# Is there a way to always return a List of Maps for Gremlin match queries with select?

Tags: java, gremlin

I have the following code:

```
    Vertex v = g.addV().property("valueStr", "3").next();
    Vertex v2 = g.addV().property("valueStr", "4").next();
    Vertex v3 = g.addV().property("valueStr", "5").next();
    Edge e = g.V(v.id()).as("a").V(v2.id()).as("b").addE("anEdge").from("a").to("b").property("value", "4").as("e").next();
    Edge e2 = g.V(v.id()).as("a").V(v3.id()).as("b").addE("anEdge").from("a").to("b").property("value", "5").as("e").next();

    List vertices1 = g.V().match(
            __.as("a").hasId(v.id()).outE("anEdge").inV().hasId(v2.id()).as("b"),
            __.as("a").hasId(v.id()).outE("anEdge").inV().hasId(v3.id()).as("c")).toList();
    System.out.println(vertices1);

    List vertices2 = g.V().match(
            __.as("a").hasId(v.id()).outE("anEdge").inV().hasId(v2.id()).as("b"),
            __.as("a").hasId(v.id()).outE("anEdge").inV().hasId(v3.id()).as("c")).select("a","b").toList();
    System.out.println(vertices2);

    List vertices3 = g.V().match(
            __.as("a").hasId(v.id()).outE("anEdge").inV().hasId(v2.id()).as("b"),
            __.as("a").hasId(v.id()).outE("anEdge").inV().hasId(v3.id()).as("c")).select("a").toList();
    System.out.println(vertices3);
```

It is basically node `a` connecting to `b`, and node `a` connecting to `c`.

I am doing a match query over this subgraph and each time I return a subset of the elements that were matched..

Here are the outputs:

```
[{a=v[20], b=v[22], c=v[24]}]
[{a=v[20], b=v[22]}]
[v[20]]
```

In the first two cases I get a `List` of `Maps`.. In the last case I get a `List`.

How is it possible for the last case to make it also a `List` of `Maps` or `[{a=v[20}]`? I know I can do a hack with `select("a","a")` but it seems there should be a cleaner way.

Where does the documentation explain in which cases I will be getting a `List` of `Vertices`/`Edges`, a `Map` or a `List` of `Maps` etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In place of `select("a")` use `project("a").by(select("a"))`

Comment: if I use a projection the way you describe will all cases return a list of lists? Thanks!

Comment: You only need it when selecting a single item. Each item returned is actually a LinkedHashMap (at least in Groovy and Java). Each element of the map is a key ('a') and a value (vertex in this case). UNLESS: you have more than one place in the query that assigns something to the same name. For example: `g.V().as('a').out().as('a').project('a').by(select('a'))` returns list of maps where each value is a list of vertex rather than just the vertex.